# python seems to skip escape char "newline" while reading on stdin

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pipe

I am using Python 3.x on Linux (Ubuntu) to read piped terminal content and save it to a database. So far everything works great! But there is a thing i dont ready understand - it seems to skip some of the newlines.

This is how i use my script (simple example) :

```
sudo ufw status verbose | python3 myscript.py
```

This is how the output direkt in terminal looks like (without pipe):

```
Status: active   
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

This is how it looks like after stdin reads it:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low) Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed) New profiles: skip
```

This is how my function to read (from stdin) looks like :

```
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    ldata = ""
    for line in sys.stdin:
        ldata += line + "\n"
```

Like above shown, Python seems to skip some of the "\n". Call me pathetic, but this kind of behavior bothers me. In case of very long strings/contents this behavior makes texts almost not readable anymore.

thx in advance!

Comment: Perhaps `ufw` command prints something to the stderr and therefore you can't get it from your pipe. Redirect stderr to stdout, like this: `sudo ufw status verbose 2>&1 | python3 myscript.py`

Comment: remember also it is always more efficient to write: ldata = [], ldata.append("string1") and finally '\n'.join(ldata)

Comment: If you need the piped data during invokation, you might want [`__stdin__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.__stdin__) instead.

Comment: thank you vm, for your astonishing fast answers! i will try and report!

Comment: How are you producing the output following "This is how it looks like after stdin reads it:"? `stdin`'s iterator does not remove the new line from the end of each line, so I would expect to see two newlines after each line (the one that was in the input, plus the one you add in the snippet of code).